# Why there's no new version of Opera for Linux? It got stuck at 12.16

Tags: linux, opera

I search along the net and looked at the Opera website, but didn't find useful infos.
I just would like to ask if anyone knows why there's no newer version of Opera browser for Linux systems, the 12.16 version (actually the latest for Linux OS) is kinda buggy and sometimes shows some strange behaviour.

Do they stop the development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Opera is no longer available for Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser).

> The Linux version development has stopped. As of 2013/December there
>   is no recent version for Linux (stalled at v12.16)

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately Opera no longer exists. On the Windows side, development (of the familiar, Presto-based Opera) has also stopped at version 12.16. The version number then leaps to 15, where Opera is basically a less functional Chrome (webkit-based). By version 20, you still can't customize mouse gestures or search engines. The only thing Opera Software is developing now is their mobile browsers.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist No. Opera is not webkit based. It uses the Blink engine. Webkit, or even Blink, does not reduce functionality of the browser since those are the rendering engines and have little to do with how the browser UI works. Customizing mouse gestures has nothing to do with the webkit or blink.

Comment: So I assume I need to use Windows for CSS testing

Comment: @Rob Ahh, my mistake. I was under the impression Blink was just the name of the JavaScript engine. In any case, yes, Opera (as Chrome) is now based on the open-source Chromium project. However, Opera 15+ is a significantly less functional and less customizable version than either Chromium or Chrome.

Comment: @user3019105 You should be testing your CSS in Firefox and Chrom{e,ium}, and several versions of Internet Explorer. [Windows is not necessary](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms), but you should definitely avoid only testing in Opera 12 (<1% market share at this point).

Comment: @user3019105 If you need to test the latest Opera, yes, you will need to use Windows.

Comment: @Rob There are [instructions on the Opera forums](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1831463/how-to-install-and-run-the-opera-20-for-windows-under-linux-box-using-the-wine-app-/p1) for running it under Wine. You never need Windows for anything.